# OpenERP find Phantom BOM product

Tags: ajax, odoo, openerp-7

Consider the following scenario: 
coke(300 ml) as base product and
 coke pack (6 cans) and
 coke pack (24)
 as child products through phantom BOM.

In normal receiving through "incoming shipment", if i receive pack (6 cans) it adds to base product  (coke (300ml))

I am creating a custom module to receive the products so I am using "product.product" object through ajax to get products while receiving.

Now if a pack (6) is received through my custom module  I need to update base product (coke (300ml)) stock in inventory and not the new phantom bom product coke pack(6 cans). Is there a way to do it in Openerp?

Answer (score 4):

I think phantom BOM is not the good way to do that. Check the way of 'product.pack' to do that. 'product.pack' is an object to manage packaging of product.

With packaging, you can select which package you received and add the content of the package as a multiple of the single item.

Comment: Thanks for the response Quentin.. For using 'product.pack' we need to go with product pack addon right?? it is associated with manufacturing I think... we do not manufacture, it is for purchase.

Comment: I don't see product pack addons. I think pack is by default with the product addons and you should configure it to use packs.